# How to get next key in associative array using foreach PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Example:

```
$array = array(
    'a' => 'one', 
    'b' => 'two', 
    'c' => 'three', 
    'd' => 'four'
);
```

How to get next key from current loop using foreach

Comment: 1) Please make an example of what you mean 2) Show us what you have tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get next element in foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096791/get-next-element-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Required output : current key: a,  next key: b , current key: a, next key: c, current key: c, next key: d

Comment: @skythanigai ^^ I think you probably want to include this into your question.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $currentKey = $key++;
    $nextKey = isset($array[$key]) ? $key: null;

    var_dump(array('current' => $currentKey, 'next' => $nextKey));
}
```

---

BTW, as [php.net/foreach](http://php.net/foreach) points out:

> Unless the array is referenced, foreach operates on a copy of the specified array and not the array itself. foreach has some side effects on the array pointer. Don't rely on the array pointer during or after the foreach without resetting it.

Comment: is possible to get next key in associative array?

Comment: OP has an associative array, not a 0-based indexed array. Which makes everything a bit different

Comment: You updated code only works if the associative keys are `single letters consecutive in the same case`! So e.g. `a, b, c, d`, but stuff like: `A, b, c` or `a, c, d` doesn't work