# Get JSON next and previous object in php

Tags: php, json

I have client.json like this:

```
[ 
{"client":"Jhon_White",  "age":"25", "gender":"male"}, 
{"client":"Jhon_black",  "age":"27", "gender":"fem"}, 
{"client":"Jhon_brown",  "age":"29", "gender":"male"}, 
{"client":"Jhon_orange", "age":"45", "gender":"fem"}, 
{"client":"Jhon_blu", "age":"55", "gender":"fem"} 
]
```

i use this to decode and take de info

```
$data=file_get_contents('client.json'); 
$arrJson=json_decode($data); 

$keyVal='Jhon_brown'; 

foreach($arrJson as $key=> $val) 
{if($val->client==$keyVal) 
{ $client=$val->client; $age=$val->age; $gender=$val->gender;}; 

echo $client; echo $age; echo $gender;
```

this gives me the info from  "Jhon_brown" row.

i need to do two links that takes me to the next or previous Client From "Jhon_brown" row. without knowing the name of the client or adding new data in the json.

how to Find the next client name or previous in php.

Comment: Can you apply a modicum of decent formatting to your code...?!

Comment: That is terrible code formatting, wow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get next element in foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096791/get-next-element-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Check for key `-1` and `+1`

Comment: Since the json is set up as an array you can do a simple walk through the list keeping count of where you are in the list. Assuming you start your count at 0 then you will match at count == 2. You can then access row count - 1 and count + 1 to get the previous and next rows for the match. Watch out for edge cases where the match occurs in the first or last row.

Comment: That is in the same Object this are diferent Objects

Comment: @mba12 @ AbraCadaver i try it like this but oly -1 is working
`$data=file_get_contents('client.json');
$arrJson=json_decode($data);

$keyVal='Jhon_brown';

foreach($arrJson as $key=>$val)
{
if($val->client==$key)
{
$client=$val->client; 
$age=$val->age; 
$gender=$val->gender;
};
};
echo $client;`

Comment: @CatalinPreda Please format your code better. But that said I do not see a counter variable in your code. Instead of using a foreach you'll need to use a regular for loop and access each row in the json with an index, i.e. $arrJson[0], $arrJson[1], $arrJson[$match], $arrJson[$match - 1], $arrJson[$match + 1] where $match is keeping track of which row in the json you are currently working with -- the row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to iterate through the items in a loop.

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('client.json'));
    $path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $frst = 0;
    $last = count($data - 1);

    $indx = ($_GET['indx'] ? $_GET['indx']: 2);  // Jhon_brown is: 2
    $prev = $path."?indx=".(($indx <= $frst) ? $frst : ($indx - 1));
    $next = $path."?indx=".(($indx >= $last) ? $last : ($indx + 1));
    $page = '<a href="'.$prev.'">Prev</a> | <a href="'.$next.'">Next</a>';

?>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Current Client: <b><?= $data[$indx] ?></b>
        <br>
        See: <?= $page ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edit the code as you see fit, it's just an example. Make sure your JSON file has valid JSON code inside it; alternatively, test that `$data` variable, make sure it's not `null` -which could mean invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just use the index value within the Json array.

```
$data=file_get_contents('client.json'); 
$arrJson=json_decode($data); 
$keyVal='Jhon_brown'; 
$clientIndex = -1;
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($arrJson); $i++ ) {
     if ( $arrJson[$i]->client === $keyVal ) { 
         $client = $arrJson[$i]->client; 
         $age = $arrJson[$i]->age; 
         $gender = $arrJson[$i]->gender;
         $clientIndex = $i;
     }
}
if ( (0 < $clientIndex) && ($clientIndex < count($arrJson)) ){
    // the previous and following clients exist
    // and are inbound, do stuff here
}
```

You might want to consider sorting the array and using a better search algorithm than linear search. 
Also please indent your code to make it more readable :)